# Find date and time of other devices using Bluetooth

Tags: android, datetime, bluetooth

Is it possible to find/read the date and time of other Bluetooth devices from my android device using Bluetooth?

NOTE: Other devices are not paired with my android device.

Done enough googling, but couldn't get any answer.

Comment: There's one obvious problem I can see with this... Not all of them have RTC - so a lot of them don't even have this information. And I don't think that those that have would be eager to share any information about themselves apart from their name.

Comment: @ppeterka thanks for the info, I figured out the other way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not covered by Bluetooth specifications: Bluetooth by itself does not provide any means of publishing date and/or time - neither via Bluetooth profiles, nor via low-level functions.

You'll have to implement your own code which has to run on both sides of the connection (i.e. you need to build a time-providing app and a time-consuming app).